# How to disable unpack phase to prevent error "do not know how to unpack source archive"?

Tags: nix

with derivation

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in

with pkgs;

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "asdfasdf";

  version = "0.1";

  src = /home/srghma/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader; # this is executeable file

  dontUnpack = true; # not fu**** working

  installPhase = ''
    echo "not even executed"
  '';
}
```

I have an error

```
nix-build tmp.nix
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/x75gi70i1i57y8d3k4hhx0r3z5kjn6h6-asdfasdf.drv
building '/nix/store/x75gi70i1i57y8d3k4hhx0r3z5kjn6h6-asdfasdf.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/3hnf69pky6mqaxv4jxly9fyywqpq6iml-FoxitReader
do not know how to unpack source archive /nix/store/3hnf69pky6mqaxv4jxly9fyywqpq6iml-FoxitReader
builder for '/nix/store/x75gi70i1i57y8d3k4hhx0r3z5kjn6h6-asdfasdf.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/x75gi70i1i57y8d3k4hhx0r3z5kjn6h6-asdfasdf.drv' failed
```

why `dontUnpack` not working?

---

Update: created bug issue at nixpkgs https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/65434

Comment: Aside: Personally, I wouldn't use `stdenv.mkDerivation` for this. It's intended for software where the unpack process is, well, *fairly standard*; there are other constructs that give you more fine-grained control in other cases.

Comment: Also, passing `/home/srghma/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader` is not very helpful to us, because obviously, nobody but you has a `/home/srghma`. Could you make this a [mcve], where other people can run the code and thus test proposed fixes?

Comment: ...and after trying to create a sample executable and inserting its path, I can't reproduce your bug. Which specific version of Nix (and nixpkgs) did you test with?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/0b7d04e5b47961658f586fa4ebbf549f with the transcript of the attempt to reproduce, and the much more reasonable error I get instead.

Comment: To be clear, the specific failure to repro is with Nix 2.2.2, and stdenv /nix/store/7pwc81j56n5jcbj2bg6j6rf3wz410mdv-stdenv-darwin from current nixpkgs-unstable.

Comment: Maybe you could post the output from `nix show-derivation -r /nix/store/x75gi70i1i57y8d3k4hhx0r3z5kjn6h6-asdfasdf.drv` somewhere, to give others the information needed to reproduce? (Well, we'd still need our own copy of the FoxitReader file, so maybe replace that with a well-known stub or something you can include a copy of, and *then* generate a new derivation and post it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , same here can't reporduce

Comment: with nix 2.2.2 and `/nix/store/3d547md672sl43r4rg1x7g20vcagwqa0-stdenv-linux.drv`

Comment: replied to an issue on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@FRidh wrote

> Many of the dont attributes were not yet implemented in the
>   current and past stable releases. So, if you intend to use it with the
>   current stable or older stables, use instead unpackPhase = ":".

Comment: `dontUnpack` appears to work now, just tested it. https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-unpack-phase

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in

with pkgs;

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "asdfasdf";

  version = "0.1";

  # Renamed to imply that 'src' functionality is not being used.
  executable = /home/srghma/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader; # this is executeable file

  phases = [ "installPhase" ]; # Removes all phases except installPhase

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/bin
    cp ${executable} $out/bin
  '';
}
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem, or is this solution suggested in absence of a reproducer.

Comment: this is working, but I would avoid using phases because they disable pre phases (like preInstallPhase and postInstallPhase) , which could be used by hooks

Comment: there is even an proposal to remove phases at all

Comment: [phases](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh#L1269) is just a string, for example `phases = "checkPhase installPhase installCheckPhase distPhase";`

Comment: With 18.03 release, I get `attribute 'src' missing` error.   So instead I overrode `unpackPhase` and just use that to do the same steps that above `installPhase` attribute does.  Seems to work.